# Which data structure to use to implement family tree in ruby?

Tags: ruby, data-structures, graph, tree

I am trying to create a simple family tree in ruby where I could add children through the mother nodes. Also when I give a name and a relation as input I should be able to get the output as names of people related to the given person name. 
For example, I should be able to do operations like
`add_child('Tina', 'bob') // which will add bob as a child node to Tina`
`get_relation(bob, maternal_uncles) // which should output all the siblings of Tina in this case.`

Which data structure is best to implement this and how to implement it in ruby? In my research I found graph is good approach and I was researching on its implementation since 2 days but could not find any solution.

I tried the following libraries

`RubyTree`  https://github.com/evolve75/RubyTree - This helped me to get parents, siblings, grandparents relations but I could not think of how I can use this to get relations like father's brothers(paternal uncle), wife's sisters(sister in law) etc

`weighted graph` https://github.com/msayson/weighted_graph - I used 0 to represent spouse and 1 to represent children. I could not go anywhere from here. I got confused on how to even get parents and children of a given person.

I explored a little bit about `ruby prefix trees` and `rgl gem` but I could not apply them to my application.

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's wrong with using [Struct](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Struct.html)?

Comment: It's an interesting question but it would be much improved if you included an example together with a series of questions you'd like answered that pertain to the example. On reflection, I think such an example is essential.

Comment: What happens when `add_child('Tina', 'bob')` and there are two Tina's? Or doesn't that scenario present itself?

Comment: If you're doing naive trees than any structure will do, but in the real world things get so complicated you'll need a cyclic graph structure.

Comment: @BobRodes I haven't used structs anytime.. will explore it.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I wanted to do only 2 operations on the data and those 2 examples I have mentioned in the question. 
To be more clear, I have 3 different  generations data and I want to represent them in a data structure so that I could perform 2 operations  `add_child` and `get_relationship` on that data and get results. 
Please let me know if my question is still unclear and needs more examples.

Comment: @3limin4t0r I dont have that scenario now. Right now only trying to present with as simple data as possible

Comment: @tadman I have explored graphs but couldn't understand how I can traverse through them to get parents, siblings relationship

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56519345/modeling-family-relationships-using-a-graph/56537069#56537069

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could figure out a way to get minimum relations using `RubyTree` itself. RubyTree has inbuilt methods like parent, siblings, children etc and also we can pass content to the nodes. 
So I used these to get what I want. For example for creating a spouse I created a child node to the root node and passed a hash like `{relation: spouse}` in the content. In this way I am able to apply logic by putting conditions on this hash and get the relations that I want

example:

```
tina = Tree::TreeNode.new('Tina', {gender: 'female', relation: 'root'})
mike = tina << Tree::TreeNode.new('Mike', {gender: 'male', relation: 'spouse'}) 
sofi = tina << Tree::TreeNode.new('sofi', {gender: 'female', relation: 'child'})
...... #add all children and their children like this

puts "--------siblings of sofi--------"
siblings_of_sofi.each do |sib|
    if sib.content[:relation] == 'child'
        puts sib.name
    end
end

# assume tina has 4 sons and one of them is bob and alice is daughter of bob. 
puts "--------alice paternal uncles--------"
puts alice.parent.name
puts alice.parent.content
if alice.parent.content[:relation] == 'spouse'
    father = alice.parent.parent #as per the question child should be added through mother only, therefore alice is added as a child to bob's wife and bob's wife is added as a child to bob as {relation: spouse}
    uncles = father.siblings
    uncles.each do |uncle|
        puts uncle.name if uncle.content[:gender] == 'male' && uncle.content[:relation] == 'child'
    end

end
```