# Family tree structure

Tags: c, data-structures

I  want create Family tree structure in C language using tree data structure. Binary tree use two pointers(left and rigth) but to represent family tree I need more pointers because parants can have more children but I dont know how much so I can't use any max value. I need to know how represent children dynamically.

```
struct {
//data
  array of pointers
 }
```

Comment: Use c++ instead of C and use vectors

Comment: Please refer to this and try to edit your question to be more clear: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Also, what have you tried?  Have you looked up how to implement a tree data structure?  There are tons of resources for C: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-tree-set-1-introduction/

Comment: Binary tree is not enough. I just want ask how to implement dynamically children of parents (some can have 2 children and some can have 4 children)

Comment: I wouldn't use a tree data structure to represent familial relationships. I'd use a a list of relationships as I describe in https://stackoverflow.com/a/56537069/56778. Why? Because real-world familial relationships are more relational than hierarchical.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you represent parent-child-sibling relationships in a binary tree by having the left node be the child of the current node and the right node be the sibling:

```
                p
               / \
              c   s
               \
                s
                 \
                  s
                 / \
                c   s
```

So you have a parent node with one sibling and four children, a child node with 3 siblings and no children, one of those siblings has a child, etc.

That's not the *greatest* way to do a family tree, but it should give you some ideas.

Comment: [Left-child right-sibling binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-child_right-sibling_binary_tree)